# How do I initialize a java.sql.Date variable?

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize a variable called startDate using java.sql.Date.

I've tried...

```
java.sql.date startDate = "02/04/2015"
```

But it thinks it's a string.

```
java.sql.date startDate = 02/04/2015
```

But it thinks it's an int.

```
java.sql.date startDate = 02-04-2015
```

But it displays the error "invalid character constant".

How do I properly initialize this variable?

Comment: You create it like you would any other object; but, you will need to parse the String value to a java.util.Date and use this to sees an instance of java.sql.Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and the [`java.sql.Date(long)` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) like

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(df.parse("02-04-2015").getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(2020,12,12);
```

I do not know why this is deprecated, but it is very intuitive for me.
basically year, month, day integer.

Update: 10 months ago, my further reading told me never use this old API. See here:
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/min-shi-schurr-3859468_how-to-effectively-use-dates-and-timestamps-activity-6873395326397558784-2ehr?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_ios

Comment: Attention: The deprecated constructor is not working as expected, to set the year to 2020 you have to give 120 (year value minus 1900). Use the date formatter for better readability and support of clean code.

Comment: I have now updated my “answer”

Comment: Deleting the Answer would be a better idea (IMO).  (What is the point of suggesting an alternative that is deprecated and then giving an incorrect example?)